# How can I call upon a parameter of a super class while in a sub class so that I can do more calculations with a variable?

Tags: java, reference, subclass, super

THis is the code, just for you to reference when you're curious about what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
import java.util.EmptyStackException;

public class TicketMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create a Student Ticket
        StudentTicket t1 = new StudentTicket(100,true);
        t1.setPromotionCode("KEXP call-in winner");
        System.out.println(t1);

        // Generate a general ticket
        Ticket t2 = new Ticket(55, 40);
        System.out.println(t2);

        // Generate a student ticket
        StudentTicket t3 = new StudentTicket(90,false);
        t3.setPromotionCode("KEXP call-in winner");
        System.out.println(t3);

        // Check for equality
        System.out.println("Ticket t1 and Ticket t2 are equal: " + t1.equals(t2));  // Should return false
        System.out.println("Ticket t1 and Ticket t3 are equal: " + t1.equals(t3));  // Should return true

        // Total tickets generated
        System.out.println("Total Tickets generated so far: " + Ticket.getTicketCount());
    }
}

class Ticket {

    private double price;
    private int daysEarly;
    private String promotionCode;
    private static final String emptyString = "";

    private static int ticketID;                    // Generates ticket number

    public Ticket (double price, int daysEarly) {    // Constructs ticket with given price, # of days early, no promo, assigns ticket #
        this.price = price;
        this.daysEarly = daysEarly;
        ticketID += 1;

        if (ticketID < 0) {
            throw new EmptyStackException();
        }
    }

    public int getDaysEarly(){
        return daysEarly;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public String getPromotionCode(){
        if (promotionCode == null) return emptyString;
        if (promotionCode.equals("KEXP call-in winner")) promotionCode = ("KEXP call in winner (student)");
        return promotionCode;
    }

    public String setPromotionCode(String code){
        if (code == null) throw new Error();
        this.promotionCode = code;
        return promotionCode;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return "Ticket ID: " + ticketID + ", Price: $" + getPrice() + ", Days Early: " + getDaysEarly() + ", Promotion Code: " + getPromotionCode() + ".";
    }

    public static int getTicketCount(){
        return ticketID;
    }

    public boolean equals(Ticket one) {
        if (price == one.price && promotionCode.equals(one.promotionCode)) return true;
        else return false;
    }

}
```

As follows is the area where I'm trying to do math on super parameters...
I put "price/2" within param of sub to take care of math but I still need another "if statement" metaphorically

```
class StudentTicket extends Ticket {

    private static final int daysEarly = 14;

    public StudentTicket(double price, boolean honors) {
        /*
        Student tickets are always bought by campus ticket sales agency, two weeks in advance.
        Students always get 50% off initial price.
        Honor students get an addition $5 off after the 50%, down to a minimum of $0.
        Student tickets have special promo codes.
         */
        super(price/2, daysEarly);

        // HOW DO I CALL UPON SUPER AFTER ALREADY HAVING DONE SO ???
        // I STILL NEED TO SUBTRACT 5 BASED ON HONORS BOOLEAN OF SUBCLASS
        // HOW DO I ADD AN IF STATEMENT INTO PARAM OF SUPER ???

        // All you will do is make a call to super constructor and pass appropriate parameters
        // So the idea is when I create a instance of StudentTicket and return price it should return me a discounted.
        // That means you need to override the getPrice() method in superclass to update the ticket price

    }

}
```

I was told to override the getPrice method but I don't know of any way to access the sub parameters

Comment: I think the easiest way it to declare `price` field as `protected` so you can access it from subClass.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a setPrice() method in the ticket class:

```
    ...

    public int getDaysEarly(){
        return daysEarly;
    }

    public void setPrice(double newPrice){
        price = newPrice;
    }
    
    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    ...
```

Then do this in the StudentTicket constructor:

```
    public StudentTicket(double price, int daysEarly, boolean honors) {
        super(price/2, daysEarly);

        if(honors == true)
            setPrice(getPrice() - 5);
    }
```

Because your methods are type: *public* and StudentTicket is a child of Ticket class, it should be able to access and utilize any *public* or *protected* methods from its parent.

- Or you could do as haoyu wang mentioned, and declare price as protected.